# How can I get line break on enter even when the search field is open (but not focused) in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have the search field open and press enter in my code it automatically tries to search instead of giving me a line break. I've heard that there is a way to turn off this behavior and only search when the search field has focus. Anyone know how? Currently I have to hit ESC to close the search before I can add a line break and I forget to do it 95% of the time and my editor jumps to a different section of the code. Thanks!

Comment: Ctrl+Enter will input a newline into the search or find fields.  Not sure about the rest of your question.

Comment: No, my question is not about the search field. I want a new line in my code even if the search field is visible, not a new line in the search field. If my cursor is set in my code and I hit enter, it activates the search field and searches the document instead of adding a new line where my cursor is. I have to close the search field first.

Comment: So that is very strange.  You can run `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` to see if you can tell why vscode is doing that.  If your focus is not in a search field a simple `enter` should not trigger search.  Something, perhaps an extension or a custom keybinding, is interfering.

Comment: @Mark Thank you! That helped me actually checking the keyboard shortcuts settings and I fount that "enter" and "shift+enter" had `"command": "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction", "when": "findWidgetVisible"` on them. Changing to `findWidgetFocus` solved it! Huge thanks! It was driving me nuts.

Comment: So for me the default context value for that command on `enter` is `editorFocus && findInputFocussed`.  What changed it for you?  You should add that info to your answer for others.

Comment: @Mark I added it in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `findWidgetVisible` to `findWidgetFocus` in my keyboard shortcuts settings fixed it!

```
/**
* amVim Finder Fix
**/
{
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
    "when": "findWidgetFocus"
},
{
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "editor.action.previousMatchFindAction",
    "when": "findWidgetFocus"
},
```